# Approximating Ordinal by Interval?

Tags: ordinal-data

I have a data set regarding population values as an Independent Variable , ( only one IV in this analysis) which is broken down into 6 blocks like so:

[0,2000][2001, 3000], [3001,5000], [5001,6000],[6001,8000] , [8001, 9000]

Now, the data is clearly interval, since the difference between two numbers is meaningful, referring to a population value. 
 Still, I have reason to believe the Dependent variable is (almost constant)
in each interval . Is this good-enough reason to consider this variable
as being ordinal? 
  In case it matters, I want to calculate effect relations between this data set and two dependent variables; one nominal/categorical and the other one Likert

EDIT: Is there also some condition requiring a similarity in the number of
data points in each interval? I mean, if , say, 5 data points fall in the range [0,2000] while 50 fall in the range , say, [3001, 5000] , how would
that skew the effect size? And, should I choose my range as to minimize
the difference in data points between any two intervals?
Thanks.
[0,2000]

Comment: Is there any reason why interval regression doesn't work here?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov: Do you mean in the Interval vs Likert case?

Comment: No, there is a kind of regression where the outcome can be a range instead of a single point. This approach typically relies on some strong assumptions, but it seems like a natural way to handle this problem.

Comment: @Dimitry: Thanks, will give that a try and get back with any questions.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?